# How do I set a custom value on the Kendo Combo box component?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-dropdown

I'm using an array of objects to populated a dropdown list on the `Kendo Combobox` component.

I have implemented component successfully.  I'm also allowing the user to provide custom values (using the valueNormalizer property) if the item they are looking for an item that is not in the dropdown list.

**How can I set the dropdown list to display whatever value they've added to the combo box, so that when they navigate away from the page, they can return later and see that their custom value is still in the searchbar field?**

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar. You can set allowCustom property on the control to true. To use this option, you will need to either use primitive values in your data set, or set the valuePrimitive to true.

```
<kendo-combobox [data]="dataField" [valueField]="'valueField'"
    [textField]="'textField'" [allowCustom]="true" [valuePrimitive]="true">
</kendo-combobox>
```

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/ComboBoxComponent/